# Adding all digits to the left of a dash character

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to add all values to the left of a dash character in Excel while ignoring the dash and anything to the right of it but have not had any luck with LEFT() or FIND() in some of the examples that I have run across.

Some example data is

```
1.23 - 2/20
10 - 2/20
1 - 2/20
```

Which would ideally output 12.23 with SUM().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NUMBERVALUE((LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" -",A1:A3)-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365, you can use the following formula:

```
=LET(x,A1:A3,SUM(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(x,FIND(" -",x)-1))))
```

**Explanation:**

- x has values for the range A1 to A3
- LEFT(x,FIND(" -",x)-1): finds  `-` for each x, then gets the characters up to 1 character to the left of  `-`).
- NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(x,FIND(" -",x)-1))): gets the numbers. This is important has the values can be considered by Excel as text.
- SUM(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(x,FIND(" -",x)-1)))): sums the x values.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, I tried this out and it did not work on Excel 2013 so maybe that is due to the version of Excel. The output says #NAME? but the answer from Lee worked for me.